# French language support in Kaldi

Tags: python-3.x, kaldi

I am working on Kaldi but there is not info on its webpage about the language which it supports for conversion.
Can I use Kaldi for French speech to text conversion.

I need to develop an offline French learning app. I tried PocketSphinx but the accuracy was very bad. Suggestion found was to train the model with your own data to improve it's accuracy.
My assumption was that training a complete French language with it's grammer will be difficult and time taking.

-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kaldi itself is only an engine, so its distribution does not include any acoustic or language model. Given enough data (at least 100 hours) you can train your own model with the scripts provided by Kaldi. Alternatively, you can look at the [list of pre-built models](https://kaldi-asr.org/models.html), but it looks like there is no French model among them.

Comment: Thank you for your time. So is there any other offline ASR available which i can use to develop a french speaking app?

Comment: There's also pocketsphinx project, but its capabilities are limited compared to Kaldi.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I tried PocketSphinx, and yes you are right its capabilities are limited.

Answer (score 3):

I was in the same situation last year.

Recently I found : [vosk-api](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api)

It's still under development but some modules are already available.
I tested python with websockets (docker image), and the android version.
Some one have even build a [Wasm version](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api/issues/49)

Last but not least, the repo links to French models provided by [Paul Guyot](https://github.com/pguyot/zamia-speech/releases)

Enjoy.